# How to store multiple nested dictionaries with scalars and ndarrays in a file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a collection of large dictionaries which contain multiple types of data (ex. ints, ndarrays and dictionaries).

##### Datastructure that needs to be stored

```
list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

dict1 = {level_1: dict, level_2: dict, level_3: dict}

#len(dict1[level_1]) = 900

dict1a[key] = {flag: int, array1: ndarray, array2: ndarray}
```

Tried dumping in a json file but realized ndarrays are JSON serializable. I'm lost on how to approach this issue. Would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Does it need to be JSON? Try [pickle](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-pickle-example). As long as the object is serializable, it can be stored using pickle

Comment: It doesn't need to JSON but everyone in my lab uses JSON exclusively. I'll try using pickle. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also speed up my code significantly.